# JProfiler not integrating with websphere on localhost

Tags: websphere, jprofiler

I have spend hours on the issue, but without any success. Here is what I have done:

Installed JProfiler(9.1.1) in my local machine.

I have websphere 8.0.0 installed in my machine. Through websphere console I have set VM parameters as:

-Xshareclasses:none -agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler9\bin\windows\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,nowait,id=117,config=C:\Users\user\.jprofiler9\config.xml

Then in JProfiler GUI, I follow:

'New Server Integration' -> 'IBM Webpshere 8.x Application server' -> 'On this computer' -> 'JVM(ibm),version(1.6.0),jit compiler,64bit JVM' -> 'Wait for a connection from JProfiler GUI' -> Select websphere server.xml(with VM parameters added above now reflecting in it) -> Jprofiler port 8849 -> 'Yes, start the session and wait for the application server' -> Finish

Connection status runs for some time...and then following error

Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8849.Please make sure that the remote address is correct, the remote program is started properly and the network route allows socket connections.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The integration wizard adds the -agentpath parameter for you, you don't have to do that manually. Two -agentpath parameters will not work.

To see the error message, look at the `native_sterr.log` log file of your Websphere server.

Comment: Ingo, thanks for reply. I added agentpath only after all other means didn't work.Initially I added server without doing anything else. But it didn't work. Although it worked immediately with Tomcat 7. So it seems websphere has some issues. Anyways,I would look into native_sterr.log once. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried in similar way but without adding VM argument onmy own. JProfiler adds -agentpath:C:\PROGRA~1\JPROFI~1\bin\WINDOW~1\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849 " to websphere's server.xml.But I still get very same issue.

Comment: The native_sterr.log file content is important for debugging this.